# Use Aptana Studio 3 to edit files on Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS

Tags: server, permissions, aptana-studio

I have recently installed Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS on an old laptop. The server is set up to the best of my knowledge complete with Webmin and PHPmyadmin and I can access the default "It works" Apache page when I type the IP into my browser.

I want to be able to edit the files on my server with Aptana, bascially I want to create an MVC using Aptana for my web server.

When ever I go to make changes or edit a file I get the error

> Failed to save the remote file due to exception "Opening file for
>   write failed". Would you like to save the file locally instead?"

I changed the preferences on Aptana to allow read, write, and execute for everyone. However, I feel I will need to change permissions directly on my server as well? I am a beginner to creating my own web server and I couldn't find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I added:

> sudo chown -R user /var/www/

Replacing "user" with my "name"

Now I don't get an error when I save it but I am not sure if that is the correct way to go about it.